# Two sets of arguments python

Tags: python, bash, arguments, command-line-interface

I like how gdb and lldb can take two sets of arguments, one for gdb/lldb itself and one for the target application. For example:

```
lldb /bin/ls -- -al -foo=bar
```

On the left side of the double-dash '--' you can put your lldb arguments and on the right side you can put your target args. Is there a way to read two sets of arguments like this in my Python script?

Comment: well, just split the argument array: `n = sys.argv.index('--'); left = sys.argv[:n]; right = sys.argv[n+1:]` and catch ValueError when `--` isn't found.

Comment: As @4ae1e1 points out, replace `sys.argv` with `sys.argv[1:]` in my comment above (best create another variable and use that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! [ArgumentParser.parse_args()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method) can optionally take a list of arguments, formatted similarly to what you see in `sys.argv`.

```
import sys
import argparse

first_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
first_parser.add_argument('arg1')

second_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
second_parser.add_argument('arg2')

first_args = []
second_args = []
double_dashed = False
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if arg == '--':
        double_dashed = True
    elif not double_dashed:
        first_args.append(arg)
    else:
        second_args.append(arg)
print(first_parser.parse_args(first_args))
print(second_parser.parse_args(second_args))
```

This prints out:

```
$ ./example.py one -- two
Namespace(arg1='one')
Namespace(arg2='two')
```

Comment: @4ae1e1, appending *is* efficient. It takes constant averaged time (with the common double-capacity strategy). Plus, there is absolutely no need to worry about performance of argument parsing.

Comment: @4ae1e1. Why do you keep claiming it is inefficient? Again, it takes *constant* averaged time, just like slicing.

Comment: @4ae1e1: To counter your false claims

Comment: And what's wrong with my comment now? Checked it and it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97348/discussion-between-jo-so-and-4ae1e1).

Comment: @4ae1e1 Great. But what you say is utterly irrelevant: It's not my point. Please don't waste our time

Comment: @4ae1e1 man, I just pointed out you're making false (and irrelevant) claims. Is it so hard to stand corrected? When I get corrected I say, "Thanks, you're right, I removed / corrected my comment".

Comment: @4ae1e1 Yeah right. I'm really stupid to engage in this pointless discussion. So I actually benchmarked with 300000 arguments (the python3 interpreter chokes at 350000). The arguments are generated in the shell with `x=$(seq 300000)`. One script appends all arguments in a loop and finally prints the length. The other finds the index of '--' (with `.index()` and catching ValueError) and prints it (or rather `None` because ValueError was raised). Results: 0.62s vs 0.56s. I guess it's a glorious victory for you...

Comment: @4ae1e1: For the future, please consider *not* engaging poor souls like me in pointless bikeshed discussions about irrelevant and utterly wrong facts. This world needs your love and *helpful* insights instead.

Comment: @4a1e1: Yes i do. Yes i did. Seems you didn't.

Comment: I guess we're both bad at this. I said it first and you didn't either

Comment: Efficiency is not a requirement, this is a command line application.